# RestXQ [XPTY0004] Cannot convert empty-sequence() to document-node()

Tags: post, type-conversion, xquery, restxq

I have a RestXQ method:

```
declare
    %rest:path("/doSomething")
    %rest:POST
    %rest:form-param("name","{$name}")
    function page:doSomething($name as document-node())
    {
        (: Code... :)
    };
```

I tried to send a POST request to this method via XForms. As response on the client I get `[XPTY0004] Cannot convert empty-sequence() to document-node(): ().` I tried to remove `document-node()` but then the parameter $name is just empty.

The request parameter looks like this:

```
<data xmlns=""><name>Test</name></data>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Is your question why you get the error? That has to be because the body of your function must not be returning a document node. Or is your question why your function is not receiving the expected data for the “name” parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `%rest:form-param("name","{$name}")` is for key-value pairs, but your method indicates that you want `$name as document-node()`. Those two things together don't make sense.

Instead of the `form-param` you likely want the body of the POST request, for that you would use the following:

```
declare
  %rest:path("/doSomething")
  %rest:POST("{$body}")
function page:doSomething($body as document-node())
{
    (: Code... :)
};
```

See http://www.adamretter.org.uk/papers/restful-xquery_january-2012.xhtml#media-example